# Use splice and for or forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to show the coupons from a client that exist in one api. If one (or 'n') coupons exist inside of another api that counts the used coupons, i have to delete from the list that or those coupons used. The api of the used coupons response something like this:

```
{
"State": 200,
"Response": [
    {
        "IdInvoiceRequest": 104,
        "Coupons": [
            {
                "IdCoupon": 77236,
                "Code": "11#E5ZQHZ-GNH"
            },
            {
                "IdCoupon": 77237,
                "Code": "12#WM96FY-NGE"
            },
            {
                "IdCoupon": 77239,
                "Code": "14#BH92BA-E6N"
            },
            {
                "IdCoupon": 77240,
                "Code": "15#FWXNR4-XHP"
            },
            {
                "IdCoupon": 77241,
                "Code": "16#7FK5F8-TKM"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "IdInvoiceRequest": 143,
        "Coupons": [
            {
                "IdCoupon": 77238,
                "Code": "13#BN5MZB-VJ9"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"Message": "Informacion correcta",
"TotalRows": 0,
"IsCorrect": true}
```

The problem comes when i try to eliminate the used coupons. My code so far:

```
function validExist() {
  vm.getSelected =
    couponExist.get({
      idOrder: vm.idOrder
    }).$promise.then(function(data) {

      for (var i = 0; i < data.Response.length; i++) {

        data.Response[i].Select = vm.exist;
        console.log(vm.exist);
      }

      vm.otherF = vm.coupons

      for (var i = 0; i < data.Response.length; i++) {

        data.Response[i].Select = vm.isHere;
        console.log(vm.isHere);
      }

      if (vm.exist == vm.isHere) {
        vm.coupons.splice(vm.coupons.IdCoupon, i++);
      };

    });
}
```

When splice acts, only eliminate the very first coupon, but the others still the same, even when all the coupons are inside of the used coupon list. What can i do to delete all the coupons? I've heard that a way to do this is using 'forEach' o a few 'for', but i don't see the light (sighs).

Can you help me?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.splice` takes a start index and the number of items to remove from the array. I'm not sure what the other parts of your code are supposed to be doing, but here's an example of how you'd look for items from one array and remove them from a second array:

```js
var existingCoupons = [
  { IdCoupon: 111 },
  { IdCoupon: 222 },
  { IdCoupon: 333 },
  { IdCoupon: 444 },
  { IdCoupon: 555 }
];
var simulatedResponse = [{
  IdInvoiceRequest: "abc",
  Coupons: [
    { IdCoupon: 222 },
    { IdCoupon: 444 }
  ]
},{
  IdInvoiceRequest: "def",
  Coupons: [
    { IdCoupon: 555 }
  ]
}];

//Loop through the invoices in the response
for(var i=0; i<simulatedResponse.length; i++){
  //Loop through the coupons in the invoice
  for(var j=0; j<simulatedResponse[i].Coupons.length; j++){
    //Loop through the existing coupons
    for(var k=0; k<existingCoupons.length; k++){
      //If the unique identifier matches...
      if(existingCoupons[k].IdCoupon == simulatedResponse[i].Coupons[j].IdCoupon){
        //Splice one existing coupon out of the array at the current index
        existingCoupons.splice(k, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(existingCoupons)
```

Comment: It works! But, if you see the example of the API, have two "IdInvoiceRequest". Right now, this part of the code iterate over the first IdInvoiceRequest. How can i iterate over all IdInvoiceRequest?

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically you just need another loop outside of the two coupon loops which will iterate over the invoices in your response.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add some clarity to the conceptual definition of the problem you are trying to solve, then select the actual programmatic implementation.

It seems you have 2 lists and the goal is to delete all entries from the first lists which exists in a second list. One possible and rather straightforward solution to this problem would be creating a third empty list and then using 2 `for` iterative loops (an outer for the first list and inner for the second one) dynamically add only entries from the first list which doesn't exist in the second one. In addition to the obvious simplicity, this approach will also provide near optimal computational performance.

Hope this may help.